# Vuex how to Access state data on component when it's mounted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to create a Quill.js editor instance once component is loaded using **mounted()** hook. However, I need to set the Quill's content using Quill.setContents() on the same *mounted()* hook with the data I received from **vuex.store.state** .

My trouble here is that the component returns empty value for the state data whenever I try to access it, irrespective of being on **mounted()** or **created()** hooks. I have tried with getters and computed properties too. Nothing seems to work.

I have included my **entry.js** file, concatenated all the components to make things simpler for you to help me.

```
Vue.component('test', {
    template: 
    `
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="note in this.$store.state.notes">
                    {{ note.title }}
                </li>
            </ul>
            {{ localnote }}
            <div id="testDiv"></div>
        </div>
    `,
    props: ['localnote'],
    data() {
        return {
            localScopeNote: this.localnote,
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchNotes')
    },
    mounted() {
        // Dispatch action from store
        var quill = new Quill('#testDiv', {
            theme: 'snow'
        });
        // quill.setContents(JSON.parse(this.localnote.body));

    },
    methods: {
        setLocalCurrentNote(note) {
            console.log(note.title)
            return this.note = note;
        }
    }
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        message: "",
        notes: [],
        currentNote: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        setNotes(state,data) {
            state.notes = data;
            // state.currentNote = state.notes[1];
        },
        setCurrentNote(state,note) {
            state.currentNote = note;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        fetchNotes(context) {
            axios.get('http://localhost/centaur/public/api/notes?notebook_id=1')
                    .then( function(res) {
                        context.commit('setNotes', res.data);
                        context.commit('setCurrentNote', res.data[0]);
                    });
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getCurrentNote(state) {
            return state.currentNote;
        }
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    store
}).$mount('#app');
```

And here is the index.html file where I'm rendering the component:

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <test :localnote="$store.state.currentNote"></test>
</div>
```

Btw, I have tried the props option as last resort. However, it didn't help me in anyway. Sorry if this question is too long. Thank you for taking your time to read this. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: I do not understand why will you make prop back into a state? i.e a data method. I am talking about this line `localScopeNote: this.localnote,`

I think this should be a computed property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend the following steps to debug the above code:

- In the Vue dev tools, check if the states are getting set after the network call
- As you are trying to fetch data asynchronously, there can be a chance that data has not arrived when `created/mounted` hook is called.
- Add an `updated` hook into your component and try to log or access the state and you should be able to see it.

Please provide the results from the above debugging, then I'll be able to add more details.

Comment: This worked perfectly for creating both the Quill editor and setting the content of the editor using state variable. I missed the updated() hook. Thank you so much.